# How to place a 3D model in the same posion in a photo for rendering?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, image

I have a real photo of a 3D object. And I also have the 3D object’s model. I want to place the 3D model in the same position and same size in the photo in Blender. The photo I have set it as Blender camera’s background. I have used the software fspy to match the camera angle to the photo with this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAN_Bjufzo0. My task is to create thousands of rendered images as similar as possible to the real photos. Their angels in the photos are different. So I want to find the fastest way to do it.

Here is the real photo.
[image]

And I have the background image from the same view of the real photo above.
[image]

This is the 3D model:
[image]

This is what I got so far.

[image]

But obviously, the model’s position in the rendered image is not the same as the real photo one.

In addition, I know the size of the real 3D models. Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). You can use [FSpy addon](https://fspy.io/) for this. Also, if possible, find out the focal length of the camera used.

Answer (score 0):

This video mentions a software that will probably help you with aligning things up with the scene background, he starts mentioning it at about 1:38. Also, are you using hdri images and putting them as the world background?

youtube.com/watch?v=nb6rSMAooDs

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, this is the software I mentioned now its name is fspy. But also thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, I am happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

It looks very close , I have found the same with fspy , it works well but sometimes I make minor adjustments.

If you rotate the object 90 degrees and scale it down a bit it should match the photo?

Final step just to put in some lighting to match that of the original photo.